# having some problem running js code from github

Tags: javascript, github, npm, dependencies

I am building a website and I'd like to have an effect [like this](https://github.com/akella/webgl-mouseover-effects) so I was thinking to download locally the code from GitHub and do some experimenting trial/error on my computer to understand how to use that effect.

The problem is that I haven't been able to run the code if I download the zip folder and then run the HTML file, the page doesn't show anything. I also followed the section "Instructions" on the GitHub page, I've installed npm but if I execute the code npm run start1 from the terminal I get these errors (I'm currently using Mac OS High Sierra as operating system).

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path /Users/name-user/package.json

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/name-user/package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /Users/name-user/.npm/_logs/2020-09-14T18_45_57_300Z-debug.log
```

So I didn't really know how to run locally that demo, can you help to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure u extracted the zip and make sure you're in the directory that you extracted the folder in.

Comment: should use a cd command before lunching the "npm run start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me when I do it.

Are you sure you're inside the project directory when running `npm run start1`?

Also there's both `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` and you should only keep one or the other. Try `rm -rf node-modules` `rm yarn.lock` and then `npm install` again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the directory and I could lunch the local server correctly. I noticed that after I've executed the command npm install, it downloaded a folder of node modules with about 91MB of subfolders with various js and json file. does it mean that this demo, in order to work, needs all of these files?

Comment: Yes those packages are collections of code anyone can use as building blocks.
They're like ready made sauce for your recipe that helps you cook faster and more efficiently. Although you could make your own packages if you wanted to, re-inventing the wheel is only a waste of time.

Comment: The thing is that having so much material was getting me confused, and I was wondering how to integrate that demo on my wordpress site. do you have any recommendation about that?

Comment: Sorry I never used wordpress I cannot help you with that.. but surely someone else will have the answer